# Finding Median of Multiple Boxes in a Boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, median, iqr

I am newbie in R and could not find the answer to my question anywhere. I have a dataset for which I have created a boxplot. I grouped the age variable into 5 groups so that the boxplot would appear nicer and more coherent, but I cannot figure out how to find the median, Q1 and Q3 for the different age groups. If any one can help it would be much appreciated.

Attached is a picture of my boxplot. [Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItAAa.png)

Answer (score 1):

Save the boxplot and access the five number summary as shown in the below example:

```
k <- boxplot(mtcars$mpg ~ mtcars$cyl)

# five number summary
k$stats  

     [,1]  [,2] [,3]
[1,] 21.4 17.80 13.3
[2,] 22.8 18.65 14.3
[3,] 26.0 19.70 15.2
[4,] 30.4 21.00 16.4
[5,] 33.9 21.40 19.2

# medians
k$stats[3, ]
[1] 26.0 19.7 15.2
```